# How to open a work's folder through the Node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Help me please

Only now i learn a node js and the react.
Now i want to open the folder and work inside this folder. [Document](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#creating-an-app)

How can i  do this?
The command `yarn create react-app my-app` or `cd name-folder` return syntax-error

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Those commands are supposed to be typed into your shell, not passed to Node. They are not JavaScript code.

Comment: into the my shell ?

Comment: Do you have `yarn` installed?

Comment: /you asking me about this command `yarn create react-app my-app`
This command i can't install
If not
Then i don't know what this. I'm just starting to lern

Comment: Open the window terminal then run these commands. Seems you are working in node js CLI instead of window's terminal.

Comment: I was working through the "Node js" console and it didn't work
Now i'm started work through the "Node js command prompt" and earned.

Comment: Press Ctrl + D to exit Node prompt and get back to your shell prompt and try the commands again